# Stuck at accepting a socket

Tags: sockets, winsock

I just moved some socket code from Linux to Windows. After some changes to make the code work on Windows my client seems to wait at the accept function and not receiving my data from the server.

The Code for my client version

```
   WSADATA wsa;
   SOCKET sock = 0;
   struct sockaddr_in server;
   packageLength = 64;//We don't need more to get all the information
   char * buffer = new char[packageLength];

   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0) { this->Die("Failed to WSA startup");}

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        this->Die("Failed to create socket");
   }

    memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));
   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
   server.sin_port = htons(55555);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR) { 
       this->Die("Failed to bind the server socket"); 
   }
    if (listen(sock, 1) < 0) {  
       this->Die("Failed to listen on server socket");
   }

    SOCKET clientSocket = 0;
   struct sockaddr_in client;
   int size = sizeof(sockaddr_in);

   std::cout << "Waiting for server" << std::endl;
   clientSocket = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &client, &size); //Stands here and wait  
   if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        this->Die("Failed to accept client");
   }
   //Never reach here
    std::cout << "Server accepted" << std::endl;
```

And the code for the server side

```
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET sock = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in sender;
    char* buffer = new char[this->packageLength];

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0) {
        this->Die("Failed to WSA startup");
    }

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Could not create socket : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        this->Die("Failed to create socket");
    }

    memset(&sender, 0, sizeof(sender));
    sender.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sender.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
    sender.sin_port = htons(this->port);

    //Connect to the recevier
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sender, sizeof(sender)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        this->Die("Failed to connect to recevier");
    }

    //Send all data
    int amountLeft = (int)amount;
    while (amountLeft > 0) {
        //Send on chunk of data. //Packagesize is actually the size of the data portion
        std::cout << "Sent" << std::endl;
        send(sock, data, strlen(data), 0);

        amountLeft -= packageLength;
    }

    std::cout << "All data is sent, socket is now closed" << std::endl;
```

The server sends the data but the the client doesn't receive it. I have checked so the ports are right and it's local host so the IP used is 127.0.0.1

Comment: Why does the client `listen` & `accept`? And why doesn't any of them `connect`?

Answer (score 1):

> I just moved some socket code from Linux to Windows.

This code has never worked on any platform. It's pointless to move non-working code.

> My client ...

There is no client. This is not a client and a server. It is two servers.

> ... seems to wait at the `accept()` function.

There is no such thing as a client that waits at the `accept()` function. `accept()` is for servers, not clients. You're seriously back to front here. The server should call `listen()` and `accept();` the client should call `connect().`